# Mapview элементы управления

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

Доброго времени суток.
Есть приложение, функционал которого нужно частично копировать.
Как добавить элементы управления  на mapview?
Заранее спасибо.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - это сделать layout, в котором расположить кнопки над картой.  
Что-то в роде этого:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:apiKey="mykey"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Более сложный, и, возможно, более правильный - использовать overlay. Но с этим я, к сожалению помочь ни чем не могу...

Comment: я об этом тоже думал, но это не решит проблему боковых элементов, возможно существует какое то стандартное решение ? даже не представляю как это должно звучать чтобы погуглить

Comment: [Вот][1], что я нагуглил... это на стаке... мне кажется, должно помочь. Просмотрите все ответы, там в остальных тоже можно что-то полезное найти...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5985426/1659629

Comment: overlay в качестве кнопок? это же плучится не то, что нужно
в ответе приведен правильный пример, от него надо плясать :)

Comment: спасибо, для "умников" вреде меня добавлю убираем setMyLocationEnabled и рисуем поверх все что нужно ))   
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity